# generate 10 digits alphanumeric value in php with first,third,fourth digit must be alphabet

Tags: php

I need php code to generate 10 digits alphanumeric value with first,third and fourth digit must be Capital alphabet and alphabet 'o' or 'O' should not be in generated code.

Answer (score 2):

The following should provide you with the building blocks:

```
$letters = array_merge(range('A','N'),range('P','Z'));

$myRandom = $letters[(rand(1,count($letters))-1)];
$myRandom .= rand(0,9);
for($i = 3; $i <= 4; $i++) {
 $myRandom .= $letters[(rand(1,count($letters))-1)];
}
for($i = 5; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 $myRandom .= rand(0,9);
}

echo $myRandom;
```