# How to generate 5 digit alphanumeric unique ID using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unique

I have a project in which I need to generate a unique 5 digit alphanumeric ID for the user. How can I achieve this using codeigniter!?

thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but could you not just use vanilla PHP's dechex(int);?

Comment: You can check this post with quite similar requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289086/generate-10-digits-alphanumeric-value-in-php-with-first-third-fourth-digit-must

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a function for that in string helper called random_string.

```
$this->load->helper('string');
echo random_string('alnum',5);
```

[Details](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html)

Comment: @navruzm, you need to check **uniqueness** in the loop, and to regenerate, or its just a regular random string..

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [uniqid()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a unique id, then you should use a unique data from the user record (index for example) or just generate a random one and directly check it's occurrence in the DB.

Here are the two approaches:

1. [random strings](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84321/#424214)
2. [Unique IDs](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/)

Comment: First link is off, here guys
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert the user's numeric id (which I am assuming you already have) to base-36 using `base_convert($id, 10, 36);`

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code has to be written under calculation field in sharepoint list to generate combination alpha numeric item id dynamically in the incremental model.

```
=field1&"-"&LEFT("00000",5-(LEN(TEXT([field2],"0"))))&TEXT([field2],"0")
```

filed1=contains the prefix alpha value i.e (xyz,abc)

field2=contains the starting value of the field1 range i.e (1,10,20)

output: xyz-00001,abc-00010..

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to use [**UUID** for such purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), as you project definitely will grow into something more serious.

For example, here's how we do in our project UID generation:

```
<?php 
// ...
public function getUid($uid = null)
{
    while (! $this->isValid($uid)) {
        $uid = sprintf('%04x%04x%02x', mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xff));
    }
    return $uid;
}
```

or find out another thread, with [more complicated algorithms of generating **UUID v4**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)