# Generate 11 digit serial numbers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Here is my model function for generate serial numbers

```
public function getmax($field_name,$table_name){

        $this->db->select_max($field_name);
        $res1 = $this->db->get($table_name);
        if ($res1->num_rows() > 0) {
            $res2 = $res1->result_array();                  
        }
        $max = $res2[0][$field_name];
        if($max == NULL) return 1; else return $max+1;
    }
```

Here is my controller Function

```
$CardNo = $this->general_model->getmax('card_number','digicardusers');
```

I want to set serial numbers starting from 00000000001.How to change the code to get 11 digit serial numbers.Any one please help

Comment: $randnum = rand(1111111111,9999999999);

Comment: Where can i use it in this code

Comment: @suresh serial != random

Comment: can you give me example how you want to generate?

Comment: Numbers starting from 00000000001@suresh

Comment: Then 00000000002,00000000003 etc

Comment: we can do it through mysql if you are ok i can give you solution from mysql side

Comment: Looks like possible duplicate of your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527237/how-to-generate-5-digit-alphanumeric-unique-id-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your just looking for the 0'padding, use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) {
    echo sprintf("%'.011d", $i).PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/UanaJ

```
00000000001
00000000002
00000000003
00000000004
00000000005
00000000006
00000000007
00000000008
00000000009
00000000010
00000000011
...
```

Comment: Where can i use it

Comment: After its returned from the function, `$CardNo = sprintf("%'.011d", $CardNo);`

Comment: Note: you should only use it for display, weird things happen if you try to work on the value or it gets casted: https://3v4l.org/CXdD9

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function just pass param $digit

```
function randomXDigit($digits = 11) {
    return str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```